# "python -m pip install matlabengine" is givining this error "Building wheel for matlabengine (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully"

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook

I am new in using tensorflow keras using python.I am trying to run this statement in Jupter Notebook

```
import matlab.engine
```

It is givng this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlab.engine'; 'matlab' is
> not a package

For solving the above error I successfully installed

```
pip install matlab
```

After that i executed this command from this [link (matlab site)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html)

```
python -m pip install matlabengine
or
pip install matlabengine
```

Both are giving this error :

```
  (base) PS C:\Users\hp> pip install matlabengine
Collecting matlabengine
  Using cached matlabengine-9.14.2.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: matlabengine
  Building wheel for matlabengine (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for matlabengine (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 212, in get_matlab_root_from_windows_reg
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 414, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uypwibie\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 380, in run
        File "<string>", line 214, in get_matlab_root_from_windows_reg
      RuntimeError: MATLAB installation not found in Windows Registry: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matlabengine
Failed to build matlabengine
ERROR: Could not build wheels for matlabengine, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Ho i can resolve this error ?

Comment: How is this related to tensorflow and keras? Do you have MATLAB installed? It’s not just a Python package, [it’s a computing environment](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html?s_tid=hp_products_matlab), the package you are trying to install is just a bridge between MATLAB and Python, and will not build if you don’t have MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like the newest version of **matlabengine** has some error  now

So I tried the following command and solved it:

```
python -m pip install matlabengine==9.13.7
```

Python Env 3.8.16

Comment: This did not resolve the problem for me with Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.